# Disable logging with Batik Transcoder?

Tags: java, svg, batik

I'm using the [batik transcoder for svgs](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html), and every time I convert an SVG image, it produces output on standard out. I'm assuming it's using a logging package of some kind. How do I disable this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom [`ErrorHandler`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/transcoder/ErrorHandler.html) on your transcoder object by calling [setErrorHandler()](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/transcoder/Transcoder.html#setErrorHandler(org.apache.batik.transcoder.ErrorHandler)).  The [default error handler](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/batik/trunk/sources/org/apache/batik/transcoder/DefaultErrorHandler.java) spews messages like "ERROR: blah blah" to `System.err`.